# Get the selected model element in GMF editor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-emf, eclipse-gmf

I have a GMF editor with different elements on the model. Once I select any particular model element, how do I get it in my handler ? Currently, to fetch all the elements present, I am using the following code fragment:

```
PalladioComponentModelDiagramEditor diag = (PalladioComponentModelDiagramEditor)HandlerUtil.getActiveEditorChecked(event);
final List children = diag.getDiagramEditPart().getChildren();
```

I am quite new to GMF and hence this question.

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure I understand your question. If you want to find the element that's currently selected in the diagram editor, you can use the `SelectionProvider`, for example like this:

```
ISelectionProvider selProvider = diagramEditor.getEditorSite().getSelectionProvider();
if (selProvider.getSelection() instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
    IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) selProvider.getSelection();
    Object selected = selection.getFirstElement();
    if (selected instanceof IGraphicalEditPart) {
        IGraphicalEditPart editPart = (IGraphicalEditPart) selected;
        EObject eObject = ((View) editPart.getModel()).getElement();
        // do stuff with selected EObject
    }
}
```